# Visual Studio Azure SQL Server: no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server database that's being hosted on Azure, I'm using the server explorer to select my Azure account, then the SQL Server; I right click and select "Open in SQL Server Object Explorer" after which I'm prompted to enter the password.

I'm unable to go past this step as I've been getting this error (see screenshot) ever since creating the server. I've added my IP address to the SQL Server's firewall.

I've even tried connecting to it with my firewall off but I get the same error.

[image]

Comment: Double check your IP before adding it to the firewall rules. By many reasons portal may get it wrong.

Comment: I've done that already. Double checked with google and checkmyip websites all returning the same address added to azure.

Comment: Without  sharing actual credentials, you you please share your connection string format and login? And just to be clear:  it's SQL Database service, not SQL Server in a VM? And not postgres or mysql service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem, it turns out the network(eduroam) at my university was the problem. I don’t understand how or why they’d want to block Azure; but using a proxy or a mobile hotspot connects me immediately without any errors.
Thanks you all for trying to help.

Comment: Oh man! Thanks for the answer. I'm also on eduroam and after turning on a VPN, I was able to access my db.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Visual Studio from within Azure Portal and you will be automatically connected to your Azure databases. Please see image below.

[image]

Comment: Hello Alberto, I tried that before but im still asked to login which results in the same error. To make sure it wasn't my PC i tried it on my laptop which has a fresh install of VS and windows and i still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your IPv4 address by pulling up Command Prompt and typing in ipconfig.  Then go to your azure database and configure the firewall settings.  Next add a client by creating a new client name and adding the IP address you got from your computer.  This will allow your computer to access your database.  It also lets you create a range for your IP address which I recommend doing.

Comment: Hopefully the problem is solved by doing the config as described. If that doesn't work, then backtrack to standard network troubleshooting, the apparent error is that your client is receiving connection refused, so find out what IP address you are connecting to, and see if you can find out why it is refusing. (You may have network problems layered in your local network and/or ISP, ahead of your cloud's entry point.)